# Discord javascript l Deleting data from database after the time has expired

Tags: javascript, discord

I made a premium membership system to my discord bot, but the time starts to be minus a certain time, so I want to delete the data from the database when the time I set with ms expires. I tried something like that but it didn't work

[image]

I save the data as follows;

[image: image2]

Comment: A few questions:

What is stored inside `presure.${message.author.id}`?
Is the expiration time in hours or in days or longer?
What part didn't work? Is it crashing or is it just not deleting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are setting the interval to an incredibly long time. It looks like you are storing the specific time you want the function to run. You'll probably want to do something like this:

```
let interval = sure - new Date();
if(interval < 0) { // this expiration date already passed
  interval = 0;
}

setInterval(function() {
  db.delete(` ... `);
  db.delete(` ... `);
}, interval);
```

However! If you do all this multiple times (like inside the 'message' handler like you're doing right now), you're gonna have a memory leak. Make sure you are setting the intervals only once.

Also, if your program crashes, you'll have to set up all the intervals again at startup.

If I was making something like this, I would instead make a cron job to check only once per day to delete all the expired members, instead of using setIntervals.